# Checking if user input already in array of favorites not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a weather app but something went wrong for two days now.

I have two components one called Home the other called Favorites what I am trying to do is to add by input city to the favorite and delete it.

the error that I ran into is simple but I can't figure it out ->

When the user enters a city the function need to check if its already in the favorite if it is the text on the button should change to "Delete from favorites" when it's not already in the favorites the text needs to stay "Add to favorites" its works well only on the first time what means
if for example I typing Tokyo and pressing add to favorite it will add it properly and if I write it again it will still work but when I enter a new city, for example, New York I will no able to edit Tokyo again but I will be able to edit New york what means that I can only remove the last thing I wrote.

For making things clear--

I am the user and I write Tokyo in the input pressing Add to favorite it will be added
And the text will be removed from favorites
same goes for New York, but when I am writing Tokyo again the text will remain to add to favorites and it should be removed from favorites.

the function that checks if I already have the city in my Favorites ---

```
    useEffect(()=>{
    for(let i=0;i<allFavorite.length;i++){
        if(userInput == allFavorite[i].name){
            setButtonText('Remove from favorites') 
            
        }else{
            setButtonText('Add to favorites')}
        }
    })
```

---

```
The function that checks if the city name is valid and removes the city from favorites -

    const ValidLocation=new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z_ ]+$");
// if(!RegEx.test(valType))
let cityKey;
let addToFavAndRemove=()=>{
if(buttonText=='Add to favorites'){
    if(ValidLocation.test(userInput) && userInput.length>3){
        fetch(`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=lyCvf3AfRlFcehI7egWl43dndCx5vyLp&q=${userInput}`, {
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((jsonObject) => {
            
            // setCityKey(jsonObject[0].Key)
            cityKey=jsonObject[0].Key
            return jsonObject;
        })
        setTimeout(()=>{
            WeatherCondition()
            console.log(cityKey)
        },900)
    }
    else{
        alert('Invalid location')

    }
}

else{
        allFavorite.map((item,index)=>{   
    let updatedFavorite=allFavorite.filter((item,i)=>(index!=i))
    setAllFavorite(updatedFavorite)
    })
        console.log('d')
    }
}
```

Would like your help guys.

Comment: You're calling `setButtonText('Add to favorites')}` in both your `if` and your `else`, on **every** element in `allFavorite`. So the end result you get is the result for the **last** element. See the linked question's answers (it's about `return` rather than a state setter, but same issue). Instead, I'd use `some`: `setButtonText(allFavorite.some(({name}) => name === userInput) ? "Remove from favorites" : "Add to favorites");` `some` will stop the first time your callback returns a truthy value and return `true`; if your callback never returns a truthy value, `some` will return `false`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is my sandbox can you point whats went wrong i dont understand your soulotion but thank you so much for your help I've been working on that for two days without any progress https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-platform-cymzx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: The single call to `setButtonText` above *replaces* your `for` loop. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i see what you meant, the add works properly as i wished for days for that i thank you a lot but now the remove function have the same issue let me explain, if i write London pressing add the favorite and then Tokyo add to favorite when I am trying to delete London it will delete Tokyo cuse its the last one

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Any idea my friend ?